# How do I trigger/call Cloud Build from a Python Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I want to call Cloud Build from a Cloud Function written in Python 3, and pass my steps directly to be executed. I'd rather not have to roll a http request and do all the low level auth myself like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915171/how-to-run-a-google-cloud-build-trigger-via-cli-rest-api-cloud-functions).

Is there some sort of client library for Python I can use to make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new Python client library for Cloud Build that it's in **alpha**. See [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-cloudbuild). Under the covers, it's calling [this API](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds/create). You can simply do the following in your Cloud Function to call Cloud Build:

```
from google.cloud.devtools import cloudbuild_v1

def trigger_cloud_build(request):
    client = cloudbuild_v1.CloudBuildClient()
    project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
    build = {'steps': [{'name': 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker',
         'args': ['version'], 'id': 'Docker Version'}]}
    response = client.create_build(project_id, build)
    print(response)
```

requirements.txt should include `google-cloud-build`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code generated an error for me : `TypeError: create_build() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Try with this code :

```
# from datetime import timedelta
from google.cloud.devtools import cloudbuild_v1
# build = {"steps": [{"name": "ubuntu","args": ["sleep", "100"],}],}
build = {'steps': [{'name': 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker','args': ['version'], 'id': 'Docker Version'}],}
client = cloudbuild_v1.CloudBuildClient()
response = client.create_build(project_id="YOUR-GCP-PROJECT-ID",build=cloudbuild_v1.Build(build),)
print(response)
```

Original code found here: https://github.com/googleapis/python-cloudbuild/issues/30